# testing a react app with enzyme and jest - problem with find method

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

im having some trouble with a test about rendering specific amount of components. Here's how my shallow of component looks like after debug:

```
  <div className="block">
    <ul className="list">
      <Element item={{...}} />
    </ul>
 </div>
```

and here is how i want to test it:

```
expect(wrapper.find(<Element/>)).toHaveLength(1)
```

Test is failing with length 0.

**//EDIT:** - more code

So, im importing my component at the top of the test file like this:

```
import List from "../components/list";
import Element from "../components/element";
```

Then on the top of describe function:

```
let outer;
  beforeEach(() => {
    outer = shallow(<List />);
  });
```

Whole test looks like this:

```
it("should render an <Element /> if an array is > than 0", () => {
    const Children = outer.props().children({
      query: " ",
      totalItems: 1,
      hasMore: true,
      data: [{items}] // it's a shorthand.. for testing purposes theres an array with one object
    });
    const wrapper = shallow(Children);
    console.log(wrapper.debug());

    expect(wrapper.find(<Element />)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
```

Comment: Did you mean `wrapper.find(Element)`? Could you give a [mcve]?

Comment: edited the comment above and added more code and explaination.

Comment: Ok.. u were right.. Just tested and it works. Thanks.